# HttpClient GET method with string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm making an app that'll host database and communicate with web site and wpf app via Web API. So, the problem is this: how can I make GET request with string parameter? I already did similar thing, but with integer parameter. Almost the same code does not work for string parameter. Why?

Code that works with int param:
Controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetResItems")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetResItems(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new FoodOrderingContext())
        {
            List<ItemsInRestaurant> list = db.ItemsInRestaurants.Where(x => x.ItemId == id).ToList();
            List<ItemsInRestaurantVM> toSend = new List<ItemsInRestaurantVM>();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                toSend.Add(new ItemsInRestaurantVM(item));
            }

            if (toSend.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(toSend);
        }
    }
```

Code on the client WPF side:

```
public List<ItemsInRestaurantVM> GetResItems(int id)
    {
        List<ItemsInRestaurantVM> list = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52407/");
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("api/item/getresitems/" + id);
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readingTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ItemsInRestaurantVM>>();
                readingTask.Wait();

                list = readingTask.Result;
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Now, the code that does NOT work:
Server side:

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetTop10Items")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTop10Items(string type)
    {
        using (var db = new FoodOrderingContext())
        {
            List<Top10ItemsVM> list = new List<Top10ItemsVM>();

            foreach (var item in db.Items.ToList())
            {
                if (item.Type.Equals(type))
                {
                    Top10ItemsVM toAdd = new Top10ItemsVM();
                    toAdd.Name = item.Name;
                    toAdd.Price = item.Price.ToString() + " $";
                    toAdd.Ammount = db.OrderItems.Where(x => x.ItemId == item.ItemId).Select(x => x.Ammount).Sum().ToString();
                    toAdd.Total = (db.OrderItems.Where(x => x.ItemId == item.ItemId).Select(x => x.Ammount).Sum() * item.Price).ToString() + " $";
                    list.Add(toAdd);
                }
            }

            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                return Ok(list);
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

Client side:

```
public List<Top10ItemsVM> GetTop10Items(string type)
    {
        List<Top10ItemsVM> list = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52407/");
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("api/item/GetTop10Items/" + type);
            responseTask.Wait();
            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Top10ItemsVM>>();
                readTask.Wait();
                list = readTask.Result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Ammount).Take(10).ToList();
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
```

First part works like it should be. The second one does not even call the server method. You can clearly see it's almost the same code. What am I missing here?

Comment: `"api/item/GetTop10Items?type=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(type));`

Comment: @mjwills Works like a charm! :D Thanks. Mind explaining me why does my original solution works well with integer example I posted above and not with the string one?

Comment: The first works because you have a custom (or pre-defined) route that specially handles the id parameter. The first would **also** work if you used the same technique as above (i.e. `?id=` etc). But with routing you can move it from the querystring to the path (like you have with your id) for 'nicer' URLs.

Comment: @mjwills So, if I have to use it like in the first example, I need to define an extra route. Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Route parameter are transmitted via `?param=value`. Your first case only works because the asp.net template adds a default route map which looks something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Which defines that every Action method which has a parameter `id` defined, maps automatically to: `myurl/action/<id>`.

To make your second case work you have to call the action like this:

> api/item/GetTop10Items?type=something

where you explicitly define the route parameter `type` and its value.